# Solr multilingual autosuggest using Ngram & Edge Ngram

Tags: solr

I am following this [**LINK**](http://www.andornot.com/blog/post/Advanced-autocomplete-with-Solr-Ngrams-and-Twitters-typeaheadjs.aspx) for implementing Solr auto suggest using Ngram & Edge-Ngram, and its working pretty fine for "**English**" language, but I have multilingual contents in my index and its not working for cases  when I use multilingual content, say for eg : If I type Japanese its showing me content in Arabic. How to resolve this issue , do I need to use specific filters for all languages ? What is the right approach ?

[image: **When I use English**]

[image: **When I use Japanese**]